# T-SQL, OpenXml is merging xml tags into single record

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, openxml

I have this sql

```
select 
    Alias
from OpenXml(@XML, '/Entity/Aliases', 2)
with (
    Alias  varchar(255) '.'
)
```

which is extracting data from xml file

xml have this structure:

```
<Entity>
        <EntityID>123</EntityID>
        <Aliases>
            <Alias>TEST 1</Alias>
        </Aliases>
        <Aliases>
            <Alias>TEST 2</Alias>
        </Aliases>
        <Aliases>
            <Alias>TEST 3</Alias>
        </Aliases>
```

...

On return of select I get `TEST 1TEST 2TEST 3` how can i modify so i get each alias in different record ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below query

```
DECLARE @Tmp AS XML ='
<Entity>
        <EntityID>123</EntityID>
        <Aliases>
            <Alias>TEST 1</Alias>
        </Aliases>
        <Aliases>
            <Alias>TEST 2</Alias>
        </Aliases>
        <Aliases>
            <Alias>TEST 3</Alias>
        </Aliases>
        </Entity>'


SELECT  xmlData.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS alias
FROM    @Tmp.nodes('Entity/Aliases/Alias') xmlData(A)
```